# Should a Yubikey be configured with HMAC-SHA1 with "Variable input" or with "Fixed 64 byte input" to be used with KeePassXC?

Tags: keepass, yubikey

- "Variable input" or "Fixed 64 byte input", that is the question
- Yubikey 5 NFC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Both work...
- but, if you change the Yubikey configuration later the KeePass database that was created with the other won't open.
- One of the developers recommended "Variable input" to me